# how to create link depending on user input

Tags: php, mysql, forms, web, hyperlink

This is the code for the user to post the post.

```
if(islet($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    if(islet($_GET['user_id'])) {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $_GET['user_id'];
    } //Then I just have a inset into statement for my database with these 4 variables.
}
```

I have a web form that creates a post by the user.  I now want to make the user able to go back to a  page dedicated to that post for them to edit, add on to etc.

Comment: What’s `islet`? Is it a function defined by you?

Comment: You wanne make some kind of forum? @SharanyaDutta, i think he means isset()

Comment: And make your code nicer for us helpers to read. Use the key shortcut ctrl+K after selected the text that is your code ;)

Comment: sorry.  I did this kind of quickly.  The islet means islet.  sorry.  It's kind of like a forum but more like fivver.  I don't know if you've heard of it but it allows a user to create a job they would do and they can go back and edit it at any time.  I'm trying to create a form similar to this type.

Comment: “The islet means islet.” Isn’t it self-evident? And StackOverflow allows you to edit your post so that you can change `islet` to `isset`, if that’s what you mean. You’re, however, at liberty to create a function `islet` which will deal with (if you feel like doing justice to the name of the function) small islands.

Comment: Ever heard of `header('LOCATION:urlHere.php')`? Why not use a `$_SESSION` with that?

Comment: I understand what you mean the biggest issue I am having is creating a link for every post id.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the high level solution:

1. You need to create a page that expects a post_id as a parameter of the query string. That page will be accessed like this: `http://yoursite.com/show-post.php?post_id=136`
2. In PHP, retrieve that post_id: `$_GET['post_id']`
3. From that post id, pull from the DB the information associated to that id. Something like `SELECT * FROM post WHERE post_id = $_GET['post_id']`.
4. Then display the post using the information returned by the SQL query.
5. If you want to show a list of posts from the current user, create another page `http://yoursite.com/my-posts.php`.
6. From that page, write a SQL query based on the current user id: `SELECT * FROM post WHERE user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']` (assuming you have a user_id in the post table, and the user has authenticated and his id was stored in the session).
7. That will fetch you a list of posts, loop through them to get their details.

Please note that you should escape the parameter passed in the query string. There are many ways to do this so I won't go into it here.

EDIT:

This is how you generate the links:

```
<?php foreach ($mysql_result as $row) { ?>
    <a href="http://yoursite.com/edit-post.php?post_id=<?= $row['post_id'] ?>">link</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Then, in edit-post.php, you can get the post_id by doing `$postId = $_GET['post_id'];`, and then use it in the query to fetch ALL the information about that one particular post.

Comment: when you used the post_id=136 in the url should i follow that exactly or how should I go about that?

Comment: I am already that far in this.  I just want to know if their is a way to add a link for each post returned on the my posts page

Comment: It's just an example, you can build your url as you like. Are you asking about how to generate the links? Or about how to build the page that shows the info about one post? Or about how to "edit" the post?

Comment: I just need to know how to generate a unique link for each post id.

Comment: The generation is a contract between the script that handles the page and the page that "produces" the URL. If the result of one of your queries returns a post with id 136, then in your HTML file do <a href="http://yoursite.com/edit-post.php?post_id=<?= $queryRow['post_id'] ?>">link</a>

Comment: I tried this and I got the error unexpected "(T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), unexpected identifier(T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING).

Comment: Try to replace '<?=' with '<?php echo '. Your PHP config might not allow the shorthand PHP tag. Did you use the code from my comment or from my EDIT?

Comment: I'm still getting that same error except now I am getting it on the last line on my file

Comment: The code in my answer has to go outside of PHP tags. Can you paste the surrounding code?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a unique ID column in your database - call it 'postid', and set it to autoincrement with every new entry.

That way you'll be sure to have a unique identifier for each entry you insert in to the database.

You then need to retrieve a list of items in the database, including the postid, and for each row in the database provide a link to display it.

If a postid is selected in the url, then display information for that post. If it isn't, then show a list:

```
<?

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databasename;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');

    ///No post id selected, display a list of everything
    if(!$_GET['postid']) {

    print "You're listing all the rows in the database<br/>"; 

    $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `postid`,`name` FROM `table` ORDER by postid ASC");
    $query->execute();
    while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

      print "<a href=\"?post_id=".$row['postid']."\">".$row['name']."</a><br/>";
    }

    } else { //A post ID is selected

    $postid = $_GET['postid'];

    Print "Select from the database where postid = ".$postid;

    $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `postid`, `name`, `keywords`, `description` FROM `table` WHERE `postid` = '$postid' LIMIT 1");
    $query->execute();
    while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $name = $row['name'];
    $keywords = $row['keywords'];
    $description = $row['description'];

      print 'Displaying details for '.$name.': '.$keywords.', '.$description.' - create edit links here... <br/><br/>';
    }


    } //End post id is selected




?>
```